# TensorFlow (Neural Network) FC output size

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Not sure whether my question is TF specific or just NNs in general but i have created a CNN using tensorflow. and im having trouble understanding why the size of the output on my fully connected layer is what it is.

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 32, 32, 3])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None])
is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

# define model
def complex_model(X,y,is_training):

    # conv layer
    wconv_1 = tf.get_variable('wconv_1', [7 ,7 ,3, 32])
    bconv_1 = tf.get_variable('bconv_1', [32])

    # affine layer 1
    w1 = tf.get_variable('w1', [26*26*32//4, 1024])  #LINE 13
    b1 = tf.get_variable('b1', [1024])

    # batchnorm params   

    bn_gamma = tf.get_variable('bn_gamma', shape=[32]) #scale
    bn_beta = tf.get_variable('bn_beta', shape=[32] ) #shift

    # affine layer 2
    w2 = tf.get_variable('w2', [1024, 10])
    b2 = tf.get_variable('b2', [10])


    c1_out = tf.nn.conv2d(X, wconv_1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID") + bconv_1
    activ_1 = tf.nn.relu(c1_out)

    mean, var = tf.nn.moments(activ_1, axes=[0,1,2], keep_dims=False)
    bn = tf.nn.batch_normalization(act_1, mean, var, bn_gamma, bn_beta, 1e-6)
    mp = tf.nn.max_pool(bn, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID')

    affine_in_flat = tf.reshape(mp, [-1, 26*26*32//4])

    affine_1 = tf.matmul(affine_in_flat, w1) + b1
    activ_2 = tf.nn.relu(affine_1)

    affine_2 = tf.matmul(activ_2, w2) + b2
    return affine_2

    #print(affine_2.shape)
```

In line 13 where i set the value of w1 i would have expected to just put:

```
w1 = tf.get_variable('w1', [26*26*32, 1024])
```

however if i run the code with the line shown above and with

```
affine_in_flat = tf.reshape(mp, [-1, 26*26*32])
```

my output size is 16,10 instead of 64,10 which is what i would expect given the initialisations below:

```
x = np.random.randn(64, 32, 32,3)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    with tf.device("/cpu:0"): #"/cpu:0" or "/gpu:0"
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        #print("train", x.size, is_training, y_out)
        ans = sess.run(y_out,feed_dict={X:x,is_training:True})
        %timeit sess.run(y_out,feed_dict={X:x,is_training:True})
        print(ans.shape)
        print(np.array_equal(ans.shape, np.array([64, 10])))
```

can anybody tell me why i need to divide the size of w1[0] by 4?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `print` statements for `bn` and `mp` I get:

`bn`: `<tf.Tensor 'batchnorm/add_1:0' shape=(?, 26, 26, 32) dtype=float32>`

`mp`: `<tf.Tensor 'MaxPool:0' shape=(?, 13, 13, 32) dtype=float32>`

Which would seem to be due to the `strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]` on the max pooling (but to maintain `26, 26` you'd also need `padding='SAME'`).